# Javascript dropdown won't close on click, obfuscated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, deobfuscation

Thanks for looking at my post - I'm trying to figure out how to make this dropdown menu close upon clicking a link but my javascript skills are sorely lacking and the code seems to be obfuscated. This is the HTML:

```
<nav class="site-nav" role="navigation">
  <ul class="pos-ul">                
    <li><a href="#menus" data-target="menus">Menu</a></li>
     <li><a href="#bar" data-target="bar">Wine + Cocktails</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="" class="mobile-trigger no-scroll">Menu</a>
</nav>
```

And the minified javascript I think is controlling it is at http://sabiopleasanton.com/js/core.min.js

The website in question is http://sabiopleasanton.com and the dropdown menu appears when the screen width is below 768px.  Thank you for any consideration at all, I apologize for any lack of clarity or shortcomings re: posting protocol.

Comment: post your js code - not minifed within your thread, please..

Comment: So, I'm guessing this isn't your webpage or JavaScript code... are you trying to make an extension/bookmarklet or something?  Or were you given this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember helping you with the slider transition on this page the other day. Anyway, this is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {

        $('ul.pos-ul > li > a').click(function() {
            $('.pos-ul').hide()
        });
    }

});
```

It'll select an anchor tag within the mobile nav, on click it'll hide the dropdown unordered list. Just edited it to wrap it in a document ready function, shorten the selector and make sure it only fires when the viewport is 768px or less.

Comment: Twice in three days you've fixed my issue!  You're a serious dude Rashad,  thanks again on behalf of me and my colleagues.

Comment: @phillydigital Glad you got it sorted, I've run into the same contingency in the past with mobile navs - usually if they're built on a framework there's a class you can add to a container that takes care of it, but a JS fix is the next best thing.